# SOAP Providr login info?

Tags: php, soap

I did some tests with providr.io.
I can get the information from the site but when I use the providr-generated packet locally I get a "999" error

The login information (credentials) is not present in the request, in which file should I enter the login and password?

My Code (using the tutorial.php file) :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Minimal options
 */
$options = array(
    \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_URL => 'http://www.gls-group.eu/276-I-PORTAL-WEBSERVICE/services/ParcelShopSearch/wsdl/2010_01_ParcelShopSearch.wsdl',
    \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_TRACE => true,
    \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_CLASSMAP => ClassMap::get(),
    \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_LOGIN => 'mylog',
    \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_PASSWORD => 'mypass',
);


$id = "2500686161";
/**
 * Samples for Get ServiceType
 */
$get = new \ServiceType\Get($options);
/**
 * Sample call for GetParcelShopById operation/method
 */
if ($get->GetParcelShopById(new \StructType\GetParcelShopByIdRequestType($id)) !== false) {
    print_r($get->getResult());
} else {
    print_r($get->getLastError());
}
```

What I get from the browser :

```
  StructType\GetParcelShopByIdResponseType Object ( [ExitCode] => StructType\GLSExitCode Object ( [ErrorCode] => 999 [ErrorDscr] => ) [ParcelShop] => StructType\GLSParcelShop Object ( [ParcelShopId] => [Address] => StructType\GLSAddress Object ( [Name1] => [Street1] => [ZipCode] => [City] => [Country] => [Name2] => [Name3] => [ContactName] => [BlockNo1] => [Street2] => [BlockNo2] => [Province] => ) [Phone] => StructType\GLSPhonenumber Object ( [Country] => [Region] => [Contact] => [Extension] => ) [Mobile] => StructType\GLSPhonenumber Object ( [Country] => [Region] => [Contact] => [Extension] => ) [Fax] => StructType\GLSPhonenumber Object ( [Country] => [Region] => [Contact] => [Extension] => ) [Email] => [URL] => [GLSCoordinates] => StructType\GLSCoordinates Object ( [Latitude] => 0 [Longitude] => 0 ) [GLSWorkingDay] => ) )
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: Please post your question in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
/**
 * Sample call for GetParcelShopById operation/method
 */
if ($get->GetParcelShopById(new \StructType\GetParcelShopByIdRequestType("*ID*", new \StructType\GLSUserCredentials($userName = "*MyUserName*", $password = '*MyPassword*'))) !== false) {
    print_r($get->getResult());    
} else {
    print_r($get->getLastError());

}
```

The *value* we need to be replaced by your personal info

Answer (score 0):

You should use a WSDL to php generator that generates the PHP SDK in order to easeily consume the SOAP WS.

Take a look to the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project. It generates the struct classes used to contruct the request and the services classes to send the request.

The response handling is then easier as you only deal with known object classes generated by the generator,
good luck,